# Android CPU usage of each function

Tags: android

Currently in my Android code what I am doing to calculate each function CPU Usage is  -

```
double start = System.currentTimeMillis();
double start1 = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();
foo();
double end = System.currentTimeMillis();
double end1 = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();
double t = (end - start);
double t1 = (end1 - start1)/1000000;
double CPUusage;
            if(t==0){
                CPUusage = 0;
            }else{
                CPUusage = (t1/t) * 100;
            }
```

I am doing t1/t to calculate CPU Usage. Is this a correct way of calculating CPU usage of each function in my Android code or is it conceptually wrong? Request someone to guide me in this.

Comment: By cpu usage you mean the %age amount of the whole cpu capacity yes?

Comment: Yes I mean the percentage amount of whole cpu capacity used by the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From documentation:](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/lang/System.html)

```
static long currentTimeMillis()
```

> Returns the current time in milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.0 UTC.

Please, replace the double(s) you are using, with long(s).

While long(s) have precision issues, they are almost irrelevant for the variables used, also, the rounding will likely be close enough, that the returned value can be used in relation with each other

Also, you are comparing two independent values. Try either the current thread, or the full thread time.

[From the Debug documentation:](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/os/Debug.html#threadCpuTimeNanos%28%29)

```
public static long threadCpuTimeNanos()
```

> Added in API level 1
>   Get an indication of thread CPU usage. The value returned indicates the amount of time that the current thread has spent executing code or waiting for certain types of I/O. The time is expressed in nanoseconds, and is only meaningful when compared to the result from an earlier call. Note that nanosecond resolution does not imply nanosecond accuracy. On system which don't support this operation, the call returns -1.

Try using, in the same Runnable (sequentially placed method calls):

```
long start = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();
foo();
long finish = Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();
long outputValue = finish - start ;
System.out.println("foo() took " + outputValue + " ns.");
```

Comment: So outputValue indicates CPU Usage in nanoseconds?

Comment: Yes. However, note the text: `Note that nanosecond resolution does not imply nanosecond accuracy` this means that while the value represents nanoseconds "minimum" value, the system itself is not that accurate. On a Sony E3, I would say I have up to microseconds accuracy..... Also, note that `System.currentTimeMillis();` before and after the function, will also compute overhead changes, memory read times etc... and `Debug.threadCpuTimeNanos();` will consider function execution time only.

Comment: Ok so i would use your solution then. Thank you :)

Comment: @Materazzi06 As a suggestion, always try the examples before accepting an answer here on stackoverflow... you cant un-accept an answer... Also, just a heads up, in your question, you are asking `way of calculating CPU usage` and then you are measuring clock cycles.... while still giving good results, you cannot measure if your process or `x` other processes are concurrent in your processor.

Comment: Adding to Bonatti's answer and comment, its not very meaningful to divide delta cpu time by delta clock time. Suppose its "100%", what does that tell you? Nothing. A better concept is to ACCUMULATE these deltas for a number of calls to foo, plus COUNT the number of calls. So have statics `long sumFooCpu` and `int nFooCalls`. Each call do `sumFooCpu += outputValue;` and `nFooCalls += 1;`.  Then some time later, output `nFooCalls`, `sumFooCpu` [if that is useful to you], and avg (`sumFooCpu / nFooCalls`).

Comment: I'll modify what I said above:  there are cases where it is useful to record both delta cpu AND delta clock time. I was just saying to not ONLY output the ratio between the two. Delta cpu is the most important value, but it can be informative to report both in millis (e.g. "115 of 300 ms", so you can detect situations where something else (that you aren't measuring yet) is eating a lot of time. Store in a dictionary, per thread, last cpu time and last clock time. Then each time ask for a delta, get current thread, so can get both, to compute deltas, then update what is in dictionary.